# How do you attract different cats?

Tags: neko-atsume

I have been playing neko atsume for a while now, but I haven't had any new cats come. I was wondering how I could attract those cats. [image: cats]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get new cats to appear you need to put out different items as they attract different cats, your food bowl also needs to be filled, if it's empty no cat will appear, to find a list of what cat like which items check out [this Link.](http://www.gameskinny.com/aythx/neko-atsume-all-cats-list-part-1-letters-a-trough-m)

This provides a list of all cats and what items are needed, in the related section on the bottom of that page you should find the link to part 2 aswell.